# Passing MSI token to flyway command line

Tags: azure-sql-database, flyway

When running the 'migrate' command of the flyway, the standard way to access DB is by providing user and password. In my case, it's Azure SQL DB and instead of user/password I have only MSI token. Is it possible to pass the token to the command line? Looking at the parameters of the 'migrate' command I couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Currently looking at the same thing. Attempting to run Flyway migrations from an Azure DevOps pipeline, using the pipeline's access token.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Active Directory MSI](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver#azure-active-directory) Authentication is supported and please see the Microsoft documentation as it has more details about how these work with JDBC URLs, ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15)) to download the driver and the applicable connection string properties and [client requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#client-setup-requirements) but please note:

> Supported since driver version v7.2, authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI can be used to connect to an Azure SQL Database/Data Warehouse from inside of an Azure Resource with "Identity" support enabled. Optionally, msiClientId can also be specified in the Connection/DataSource properties along with this authentication mode, which must contain the Client ID of a Managed Service Identity to be used to acquire the accessToken for establishing the connection.

You could run this from an Azure AD Federated on-premise host or Azure host using the following [java client example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) and then run the migrate command.

Comment: This is good answer on JDBC in general, but the question is really specific to Flyway: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver